# MongoDB search string in array of objects

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I have a structure in MongoDB that have different amounts of items in an array called "items". To make the search, I am using the following command, which first turns the contents into a string, as in this.items there is a different structure depending on the object:

```
db.getCollection('docs').find.('JSON.stringify(this.items[0].value).toLowerCase().indexOf("text")!=-1')
```

My problem is that as I do not know the amount of items that each document has, I would have to use a wildcard as this.items[*].value, but it does not work.

Does anyone know any solution, or have another idea for this?

Comment: `getCollection('docs').find` instead `getCollection('docs')find`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the $elemMatch (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

```
db.docs.find({items: {$elemMatch: {value: {$regex : "text"}}}});
```

So this query will find all documents with an `item` in the items array that contain the string "text" in the value property, after this operation you can count how much items the document has.

Answer (score 3):

You can use dot notation of `items.value` to target the `value` field of all `items` elements, and a regular expression to perform the case-insensitive sub-string match:

```
db.getCollection('docs').find({ 'items.value': /text/i })
```

Comment: Worked with regex! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate each document and apply the `indexOf`, something like this..

```
var cursor = db.getCollection('docs').find({}); // get all docs
var newOut = []; // new array of items if match with some condition
while ( cursor.hasNext() ){ // iterate all docs

   var doc = cursor.next(); // get the document in focus
   doc.items.forEach(function(item){ // iterate the items of doc.items
       if ( item.toLowerCase().indexOf("text") !== -1 ) // check if text exists in array
           newOut.push(item); // add to new array
   });

};
printjson(newOut);
```